# map through local json with images and data in React

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary

### I am trying to map through a local JSON file in React that has images and data, the data renders but the images render the URL and not the image, probably is a very basic question but if someone can help me, please, the best I could achieve was to render only one of the images, but I want to map through all of them and render them.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import MovieSummary from "../components/MovieSummary";

const MovieSummaries = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="MovieSummaries_container">
        {data.map((data, key) => {
          return (
            <MovieSummary
              key={key}
              Title={data.Title}
              Poster={data.Poster}
              Year={data.Year}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MovieSummaries;

MovieSummaries.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      Title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      Poster: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
      Year: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    })
  ),
};
```

```
[
  {
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "Year": "2009",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "18 Dec 2009",
    "Runtime": "162 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
    "Director": "James Cameron",
    "Writer": "James Cameron",
    "Actors": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang",
    "Plot": "A paraplegic marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
    "Language": "English, Spanish",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "83",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
    "imdbVotes": "890,617",
    "imdbID": "tt0499549",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyOTYyMzUxNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTg0MTUzNA@@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzM2MDk3MTcyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjg0MTUzNA@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY2ODQ3NjMyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODg0MTUzNA@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxOTEwNDcxN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0MTUzNA@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYxMDg1Nzk1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDk0MTUzNA@@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Title": "I Am Legend",
    "Year": "2007",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "14 Dec 2007",
    "Runtime": "101 min",
    "Genre": "Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Francis Lawrence",
    "Writer": "Mark Protosevich (screenplay), Akiva Goldsman (screenplay), Richard Matheson (novel), John William Corrington, Joyce Hooper Corrington",
    "Actors": "Will Smith, Alice Braga, Charlie Tahan, Salli Richardson-Whitfield",
    "Plot": "Years after a plague kills most of humanity and transforms the rest into monsters, the sole survivor in New York City struggles valiantly to find a cure.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "9 wins & 21 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4NzMyNDk1OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTEwMzU1MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "65",
    "imdbRating": "7.2",
    "imdbVotes": "533,874",
    "imdbID": "tt0480249",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI0NTI4NjE3NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMDA0Nzc4._V1_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTIwMDg2MDU4M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMTA0Nzc4._V1_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5MDM1OTU5OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjA0Nzc4._V1_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTA0MTI2NjMzMzFeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU2MDMwNDc3OA@@._V1_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Title": "300",
    "Year": "2006",
    "Rated": "R",
    "Released": "09 Mar 2007",
    "Runtime": "117 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Drama, Fantasy",
    "Director": "Zack Snyder",
    "Writer": "Zack Snyder (screenplay), Kurt Johnstad (screenplay), Michael Gordon (screenplay), Frank Miller (graphic novel), Lynn Varley (graphic novel)",
    "Actors": "Gerard Butler, Lena Headey, Dominic West, David Wenham",
    "Plot": "King Leonidas of Sparta and a force of 300 men fight the Persians at Thermopylae in 480 B.C.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "16 wins & 42 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzNTkzNjcxNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDA4NjE3._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "52",
    "imdbRating": "7.7",
    "imdbVotes": "611,046",
    "imdbID": "tt0416449",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNTg5MzMwMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzA2NTIyMw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,937_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQwNTgyNTMzNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDA2NTIyMw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,935_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc0MjQzOTEwMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzE2NTIyMw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,947_AL_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Title": "The Avengers",
    "Year": "2012",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "04 May 2012",
    "Runtime": "143 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller",
    "Director": "Joss Whedon",
    "Writer": "Joss Whedon (screenplay), Zak Penn (story), Joss Whedon (story)",
    "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Hemsworth",
    "Plot": "Earth's mightiest heroes must come together and learn to fight as a team if they are to stop the mischievous Loki and his alien army from enslaving humanity.",
    "Language": "English, Russian",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 34 wins & 75 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk2NTI1MTU4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODg0OTY0Nw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "69",
    "imdbRating": "8.1",
    "imdbVotes": "1,003,301",
    "imdbID": "tt0848228",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTA0NjY0NzE4OTReQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDczODg2Nzc@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE1MzEzMjcyM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDM4ODY3Nw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjMwMzM2MTg1M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjM4ODY3Nw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ4NzM2Mjc5MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTkwOTY3Nw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc3MzQ3NjA5N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzY5OTY3Nw@@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Title": "The Wolf of Wall Street",
    "Year": "2013",
    "Rated": "R",
    "Released": "25 Dec 2013",
    "Runtime": "180 min",
    "Genre": "Biography, Comedy, Crime",
    "Director": "Martin Scorsese",
    "Writer": "Terence Winter (screenplay), Jordan Belfort (book)",
    "Actors": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Jonah Hill, Margot Robbie, Matthew McConaughey",
    "Plot": "Based on the true story of Jordan Belfort, from his rise to a wealthy stock-broker living the high life to his fall involving crime, corruption and the federal government.",
    "Language": "English, French",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 5 Oscars. Another 35 wins & 154 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxMjgxNTk0MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIyOTg2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "75",
    "imdbRating": "8.2",
    "imdbVotes": "786,985",
    "imdbID": "tt0993846",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDIwMDIxNzk3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTg0MzQ4MDE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc0NzAxODAyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDg0MzQ4MDE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTExMDk1MDE4NzVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDM4NDM0ODAx._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg3MTY4NDk4Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjc0MzQ4MDE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTgzMTg4MDI0Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTY0MzQ4MDE@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,1553,1000_AL_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Title": "Interstellar",
    "Year": "2014",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "07 Nov 2014",
    "Runtime": "169 min",
    "Genre": "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan",
    "Actors": "Ellen Burstyn, Matthew McConaughey, Mackenzie Foy, John Lithgow",
    "Plot": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 1 Oscar. Another 39 wins & 134 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "74",
    "imdbRating": "8.6",
    "imdbVotes": "937,412",
    "imdbID": "tt0816692",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA3NTEwOTMxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjMyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzQ5ODE2MzEwM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTMyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4Njk4MzY0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzIyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzE3MTM0MTc3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDIyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjYzNjE2NDk3N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzEyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "ComingSoon": true,
    "Title": "Doctor Strange",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Rated": "N/A",
    "Released": "04 Nov 2016",
    "Runtime": "N/A",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
    "Director": "Scott Derrickson",
    "Writer": "Scott Derrickson (screenplay), C. Robert Cargill (screenplay), Jon Spaihts (story by), Scott Derrickson (story by), C. Robert Cargill (story by), Steve Ditko (comic book)",
    "Actors": "Rachel McAdams, Benedict Cumberbatch, Mads Mikkelsen, Tilda Swinton",
    "Plot": "After his career is destroyed, a brilliant but arrogant and conceited surgeon gets a new lease on life when a sorcerer takes him under her wing and trains him to defend the world against evil.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "N/A",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNjgwNzAzNjk1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzQ2NjI1OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "N/A",
    "imdbRating": "N/A",
    "imdbVotes": "N/A",
    "imdbID": "tt1211837",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjM3ODc1ODI5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODMzMDY3OTE@._V1_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTgxNTAyNTU0NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzMzMDY3OTE@._V1_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE5NDc5NzUwNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDM3MDM2NzE@._V1_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "ComingSoon": true,
    "Title": "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Rated": "N/A",
    "Released": "16 Dec 2016",
    "Runtime": "N/A",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Gareth Edwards",
    "Writer": "Chris Weitz (screenplay), Tony Gilroy (screenplay), John Knoll (story), Gary Whitta (story), George Lucas (characters)",
    "Actors": "Felicity Jones, Riz Ahmed, Mads Mikkelsen, Ben Mendelsohn",
    "Plot": "The Rebellion makes a risky move to steal the plans to the Death Star, setting up the epic saga to follow.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "1 nomination.",
    "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQyMzI2OTA3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDg5NjQ0OTE@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,674,1000_AL_.jpg",
    "Metascore": "N/A",
    "imdbRating": "N/A",
    "imdbVotes": "N/A",
    "imdbID": "tt3748528",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE3MzA4Nzk3NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjAxMTc1ODE@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,744_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDMxMTQzMjQxM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzAxMTc1ODE@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,744_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUyNjkxOTk5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODAxMTc1ODE@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,744_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM4MzExNDAyNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTAxMTc1ODE@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,744_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE3NTgxMDcyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDExMTc1ODE@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,744_AL_.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "ComingSoon": true,
    "Title": "Assassin's Creed",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Rated": "N/A",
    "Released": "21 Dec 2016",
    "Runtime": "N/A",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
    "Director": "Justin Kurzel",
    "Writer": "Bill Collage (screenplay), Adam Cooper (screenplay), Michael Lesslie (screenplay)",
    "Actors": "Michael Fassbender, Michael Kenneth Williams, Marion Cotillard, Jeremy Irons",
    "Plot": "When Callum Lynch explores the memories of his ancestor Aguilar and gains the skills of a Master Assassin, he discovers he is a descendant of the secret Assassins society.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "UK, France, USA, Hong Kong",
    "Awards": "N/A",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2MTQwMjU1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDA5NjU5ODE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "N/A",
    "imdbRating": "N/A",
    "imdbVotes": "N/A",
    "imdbID": "tt2094766",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True",
    "Images": [
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BN2EyYzgyOWEtNTY2NS00NjRjLWJiNDYtMWViMjg5MWZjYjgzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjUwNzk3NDc@._V1_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOWYzOTctOTc4My00ZmJkLTgzMTctMmUxNDI5ODQzYzNjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDAyODU1Njc@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTY5ZGUxMTAtYTU0OC00NGQ2LTkzNzgtZGZmNjlmNjY3MGU0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTY0MTkxMTg@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,1500,1000_AL_.jpg",
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjA0MWYwZTEtYzc5Yi00NGM2LTg1YTctNjY2YzQ0NDJhZDAwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDAyODU1Njc@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,1499,1000_AL_.jpg"
    ]
  }
]
```

```
import React from "react";

const MovieSummary = (props) => {
  const { Title, Poster, Year } = props;

  return (
    <div className="Movie-summary">
      <div className="Movie-summary_title">{Title}</div>
      <div className="Movie-summary_Poster">{Poster}</div>
      <div className="Movie-summary_year">{Year}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieSummary;
```

Comment: You can take that `data.Images` array and map from it.